# Referencing Python list elements without specifying indexes

Tags: python, indexing

How can I store values in a list without specifying index numbers?

For example

```
outcomeHornFive=5

someList = []
someList.append(outComeHornFive)
```

instead of doing this,

```
someList[0] # to reference horn five outcome
```

how can i do something like this? The reason is there are many items that I need to reference within the list and I just think it's really inconvenient to keep track of which index is what.

```
someList.hornFive
```

Comment: @hayk.mart Just an hour ago, we pressed for him to use a list or other collection instead of creating variables dynamically. Mixed signals are bad.

Comment: I thought we pressed him not to use a list (which is what I meant by array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another data structure if you'd like to reference things by attribute access (or otherwise via a name).

You can put them in a `dict`, or create a class, or do something else. It depends what kind of other interaction you want to have with that object.

(P.S., we call those lists, not arrays).

Comment: Perhaps a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) if you know if advance what your fields will be.

Comment: Yep, that'd be another option if immutability were OK and you can stomach `namedtuple` :P.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a list you can use a dictionary.

See [data types](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) in the python documentation.

A dictionary allows you to lookup a value using a key:

```
my_dict["HornFive"] = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and you shouldn't. If you could do that, how would you refer to the list itself? And you *will* need to refer to the list itself.

> The reason is there are many items that i need to reference within the list and I just think it's really inconvenient to keep track of which index is what.

You'll need to do something of that ilk anyway, no matter how you organize your data. If you had separate variables, you'd need to know which variable stores what. If you had your way with this, you'd still need to know that a bare `someList` refers to "horn five" and not to, say, "horn six".
One advantage of lists and dicts is that you can factor out this knowledge and write generic code. A dictionary, or even a custom class (*if* there is a finite number of semantically distinct attributes, and you'd never have to use it as a collection), may help with the readability by giving it an actual name instead of a numeric index.

Answer (score 0):

referenced from http://parand.com/say/index.php/2008/10/13/access-python-dictionary-keys-as-properties/

Say you want to access the values if your dictionary via the dot notation instead of the dictionary syntax. That is, you have:

```
d = {'name':'Joe', 'mood':'grumpy'}
```

And you want to get at “name” and “mood” via

d.name
d.mood

instead of the usual

```
d['name']
d['mood']
```

Why would you want to do this? Maybe you’re fond of the Javascript Way. Or you find it more aesthetic. In my case I need to have the same piece of code deal with items that are either instances of Django models or plain dictionaries, so I need to provide a uniform way of getting at the attributes.

Turns out it’s pretty simple:

```
class DictObj(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def __getattr__(self, m):
        return self.d.get(m, None)

d = DictObj(d)
d.name
# prints Joe
d.mood
# prints grumpy
```

Comment: This is really icky. In Python attribute access and indexing are two different operations, and they shouldn't be mixed like this. If you like the way JS does it, use JS (that's a serious suggestion, not a dismissal, JS has it's own different paradigms). It sounds like your function is poorly designed and has two different kinds of input coming in. That might mean it deserves to be two different functions.

Comment: i'm just used to using getters and setters. I guess this would be a poor practice in Python. Thanks for clarifying it again.